# Rails, subtracting dates in nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, activerecord, model

Hoping someone can help me here, think I am not seeing something simple.

I'm trying to subtract Date.today from a date field in a nested model.

When I have:

```
Date.today - Photo.minimum(:date)
```

This works fine, and calculates the difference between the two dates.

But when I have:

```
Date.today - site.photos.minimum(:date)
```

This throws an 'expected numeric' error. I get the same error when I try Photo.where(site_id: site.id).minimum(:date).

Am I missing something with this error? How come when I use the nested model, it won't calculate the date difference?

My associations are Site has many photos. Photo belongs_to Site.

Comment: what do `Photo.minimum(:date)` and `site.photos.minimum(:date)` return?

Comment: They both return the same thing: 2017-08-06

Comment: I'm assuming `date` is referring to a database column, is that column a date column? Because if I run `Date.today - '2017-08-06'.to_date` I don't get that error, without `.to_date` I get the same error as you.

Comment: It definitely is a date column.

Comment: does adding `.to_date` to `site.photos.minimum(:date)` change anything?

Comment: What `Photo.last.date.class` returns? It’s weird, but the error happens because `site.photos.minimum(:date)` returns a time instance. FWIW, using `Date.today` is a code smell in Rails; one should always use `Time.zone.now`. Otherwise sooner or later you’ll get into problems with different timezones.

Comment: I'm able to replicate the error in a database in my project, but only when calling `.minimum` on the collection returns nil, which is the case if no item in the collection has that date field populated.

Comment: @mudasobwa Both statements return a class Date

Comment: @moveson Hmm, date is definitely populated in my collection as both Photo.minimum(:date), and site.photos.minimum(:date) return the same date, 2017-08-06

Comment: @moveson - I believe you had the correct solution. Do you want to repost it and I will accept.

Comment: @moveson lol - no I believe you posted answer with some code, then deleted it....

Answer (score 1):

The error says that it expects a numeric suggesting that one of your values isn't numeric.  You can test the class of each or simply just convert them to an integer using .to_i and perform the calculation after that.

https://apidock.com/ruby/Time/to_i